# Why only one unbounded connected component

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

[Here](http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/gsm-40-r-prev.pdf) on page 344 it is stated that

If $U \subset \mathbb C$ is bounded then $\mathbb C \setminus U$ has exactly one unbounded component.

While it seems sort of clear to me in an intuitive way I don't quite see how to prove it. I know that connected components of a space are closed sets but I didn't manage to use it to construct a proof. How to prove it?

Comment: If $U \subset D_R(0)$, then $\mathbb{C}\setminus D_R(0)$ is a connected set, hence contained in a single component $C$. What does that tell you about the other components of $\mathbb{C}\setminus U$?

Comment: @DanielFischer perfect as always (might I suggest an answer to that effect?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $U$ is bounded, then there is an $R > 0$ such that $U \subset D_R(0)$. Then the complement of the disk, $\mathbb{C}\setminus D_R(0)$ is connected, hence it is contained in one connected component $C_0$ of $\mathbb{C}\setminus U$. Therefore all other connected components of $\mathbb{C}\setminus U$ are contained in (a certain bounded set).